# ANDROID [Back Button causes crash]

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, android-intent

So I have 3 Activities (LauncherActivity>MenuAvtivity>SelectionActivity)
When I press the back button to go back from the SelectionActivity to the MenuActivity my app chrashes.

```
Code: Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this,SelectionActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Error Code:

```
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 14823
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:871)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1025)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.example.myapp.MenuView$1.surfaceCreated(MenuView.java:51)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:662)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:256)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:8096)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1110)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1448)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
12-21 20:37:52.179: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The LauncherActivity is using a SurfaceView and the MenuActivity a SurfaceView with a Thread drawing on a Canvas.

Thread Class:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        Canvas c = null;
        try {
            c = menuView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (menuView.getHolder()) {
                menuView.doDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                menuView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started

So in your surfaceCreated you're calling thread.start.  However that thread was already started previously.  So either don't start it again, or create a new Thread.  My guess is the first one is the right answer, but without code I can't tell for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Can I stop the Thread when I leave the Activity and start it again when I press the back button.

Comment: @SanPonko Don't know.  What does the documentation say?

Comment: Yes, but do not call Thread.stop.  That's the wrong way to do it.  The right way to do it is to have a synchronization primitive checked at the top of the loop in your Thread-  usually a semaphore.  Take the semaphore in onPause and release it in onResume.  Then have your Thread block until its available at the top of its loop